# Position absolute makes the other content element not flexible

Tags: html, css

I have 2 contents, the first one is blue section and the second one is purple section.

I add position absolute in the second section since I want to make the content share background, half with blue section and purple section.

My question, if I add more text on the first section, the text for the first section is hidden behind the second section.

Is there a way to make the first section flexible?
So whenever I add more text, the second section will not hide the text.

```css
.commercial-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
  bottom: 320px;
}

.commercial-white {
  background-color: #f1f1f4;
  width: 340px;
  height: 460px;
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  border-bottom: 15px solid #005da0;
  margin: 10px;
}

.commercial-blue {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #005da0;
  color: #ffffff;
  width: 340px;
  height: 473px;
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  margin: 10px;
  border: 2px solid #ffffff;
  visibility: hidden;
}

.open.commercial-blue {
  visibility: visible;
}

.commercial-flip {
  padding: 20px;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.main-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  background-color: purple;
  justify-content: center;
}

.commercial-wrapper-text {
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #215cad;
  color: #ffffff;
  padding: 20px 0;
  height: 500px;
}

.commercial-main-wrapper-flip {
  background-color: purple;
  position: relative;
  height: 200px;
}

.commercial-wrapper-flip {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  position: relative;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

#industry-block {
  background-color: #dce5ee;
}

.commit-industry {
  border: 1px solid purple;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
 <div class="commercial-solution-wrapper">
        <div class="commercial-wrapper-text">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.<br />
                <br />

            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.<br />
                <br />
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.<br />
                <br />
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="commercial-main-wrapper-flip">
        <div class="commercial-wrapper-flip">

            <div class="commercial-wrapper">
                <div class="commercial-white">
                    <div class="commercial-flip">
                        <h3>Lorem ipsum</h3>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>

            <div class="commercial-wrapper">
                <div class="commercial-white">
                    <div class="commercial-flip">
                        <h3>Lorem ipsum</h3>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>

            <div class="commercial-wrapper">
                <div class="commercial-white">
                    <div class="commercial-flip">
                        <h3>Lorem ipsum</h3>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>

            <div class="commercial-wrapper">
                <div class="commercial-white">
                    <div class="commercial-flip">
                        <h3>Lorem ipsum</h3>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

[image]

EDIT: add an image for expected result

Comment: Please provide what your expected result is, such as an image.

Comment: @EternalHour Hi I added an image for expected result, basically that's how it suppose to look like, but the problem occur if I add more text, the text is hidden behind the second section.

Comment: don't use width CSS elements just use max-width instead so when you add more text it will not conflict with other container.also use word-wrap : beak-word CSS elements to break words when it hit the wall. Apply this and post results.

Comment: @Creative87 Sorry I don't understand, which class are you talking that I need to add word wrap? It's actually solved by disinfor, but if you have other solution, I'm open to hear

Comment: @Udzzzz  if the problem came from much text in containers so you need to break words using CSS also define maximum width  on that container. There's much advanced usage with java but CSS is enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are adding `position: absolute`  you are taking that element out of document flow - so the text won't ever interact with the content below (hence the hiding).

One way to do it is to add a linear gradient to the second wrapper. So you are essentially "faking" the overlap.

The important part:

```
.commercial-main-wrapper-flip {
  background: linear-gradient(0deg, rgba(191, 0, 254, 1) 55%, rgba(33, 92, 173, 1) 55%);
  position: relative;
}
```

```css
.commercial-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
}

.commercial-white {
  background-color: #f1f1f4;
  width: 340px;
  height: 460px;
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  border-bottom: 15px solid #005da0;
  margin: 10px;
}

.commercial-blue {
  position: relative;
  background-color: #005da0;
  color: #ffffff;
  width: 340px;
  height: 473px;
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  margin: 10px;
  border: 2px solid #ffffff;
  visibility: hidden;
}

.open.commercial-blue {
  visibility: visible;
}

.commercial-flip {
  padding: 20px;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.main-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  background-color: purple;
  justify-content: center;
}

.commercial-wrapper-text {
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #215cad;
  color: #ffffff;
  padding: 20px 0;
}

.commercial-main-wrapper-flip {
  background: linear-gradient(0deg, rgba(191, 0, 254, 1) 55%, rgba(33, 92, 173, 1) 55%);
  position: relative;
}

.commercial-wrapper-flip {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  position: relative;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

```html
<div class="commercial-solution-wrapper">
  <div class="commercial-wrapper-text">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
      dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.<br />
      <br />

      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
        dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.<br />
        <br /> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis
        aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.<br />
        <br /> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis
        aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="commercial-main-wrapper-flip">
  <div class="commercial-wrapper-flip">

    <div class="commercial-wrapper">
      <div class="commercial-white">
        <div class="commercial-flip">
          <h3>Lorem ipsum</h3>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>

    <div class="commercial-wrapper">
      <div class="commercial-white">
        <div class="commercial-flip">
          <h3>Lorem ipsum</h3>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>

    <div class="commercial-wrapper">
      <div class="commercial-white">
        <div class="commercial-flip">
          <h3>Lorem ipsum</h3>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>

    <div class="commercial-wrapper">
      <div class="commercial-white">
        <div class="commercial-flip">
          <h3>Lorem ipsum</h3>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Nice, thanks a lot, it's working, this is the answer I'm looking for